# C# - best way of creating a program with multiple forms/windows?

Tags: c#

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a main form and I added a UserControl named menu to it. Here's how it looks:

http://prntscr.com/a5dx0e

Now what I want is: when I select an item from the menu, the content below the menu will change without loading another form.

I could do that but the user would see a window disappearing and another appearing and that's kinda ugly.

What I really want is to replace the content based on the menu item clicked.

The best way I found was to create multiple UserControls and then just replace them with the right one. Is this a good idea or are there any better solutions?

Please note that I'm a starter in C# and I'm looking for the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tab control and hide the tab header. Control the navigation amongst the pages programmatically when user clicks a menu. I've used this technique successfully in the past.

Comment: That's a cool idea, I'll see how to hide the tab header

Answer (score 0):

Choices,

1. hide/reveal panels (ways to collect/group all of the controls you are hiding revealing now)
2. Use a multi-tab control
3. Use an MDI (multi document interface) control
4. Use multiple forms, but display the new one first, then hide the prior one.

Comment: Last job, i inherited a winforms application where all controls were stacked on the same page & shown/hidden individually, no panels or anything.  Needless to day the design view was a nightmare

Comment: from those 4 choices, the best one is the 3rd one. But I don't really like the behavior of MDI